# Automatic creation and storage of build artifacts

Tags: ant, build, continuous-integration, artifact

Not sure what to call this, but here is what I am looking for.  I have a build system that builds 3 sets of components
- server components
- desktop components
- device components
Each have their own build scripts, with an overall one that builds them all and creates a package with all 3 together.  The issue is when I build a package, I would like to not have to build all 3 sets, I would like only the sets whose source has changed since the last time a package was created.  As each component can take quite some time to build, and a developer usually only ones the set he's working on to build, but needs them all to test.

I would like to be able to request the latest package, which comprises the latest binaries of the most up to date source.  Would also like to be able to request, the package that was built for build 195, lets say.

I saw a Google Tech Talk that shows that Google does this in house.  I have found http://archiva.apache.org/, but it seems to simply be a storage mechanism.  Maybe Bamboo already does this and I have not been able to see it?

I have been unable to find the right search phrase for Google to give me an answer.

So turning to you all to see what I might find, thank you in advance.

Comment: You need a mechanism for handling versions.  Maven is frequently used for that (but takes a bit of getting used to), but then I think Jenkins can do what you need

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you could do with [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) dependency management.